# Static IP for ESP8266 based on gateway

Tags: esp8266, tcpip

I'm new to Arduino programming. I want to make my ESP8266 get a static IP address based on the gateway's IP address.

I mean if the gateway is at 192.168.0.1 then the ESP8266 should get 192.168.0.15 as a static IP address. And if the gateway is at 192.168.1.1 then it should get 192.168.1.15 as an IP address.

Comment: Isn't that the role of DHCP? Your Access Point / Router should be handing out that IP address. If you want it to be static then configure your router to allocate a static IP for the MAC address. If you're getting the gateway by DHCP then you will also be getting an IP through DHCP.

Comment: I'm wondering why you would want to do that. You run the risk of IP collissions and network problems that are hard to diagnose. I would not want such a device in my network ;-) A (Static) DHCP Address reservation is the mechanism you should be using.

Answer (score 1):

You can either set the router to allocate a static IP address based on your ESP8266's MAC address, or go the DHCP-way first, read the gateway IP address you got, and then do a `WiFi.config()`, something roughly like this (untested):

```cpp
WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
IPAddress ip = WiFi.gatewayIP();
IP[3] = 15;
IPAddress dns(8, 8, 8, 8);
WiFi.config(ip, WiFi.gatewayIP(), dns, WiFi.subnetMask());
```

It is a bit of a trick, and not pretty, and you don't get to set the DNS as provided by the DHCP, because there is no `getDNS()`, for some silly reason, hence the use of Google's DNS server.

Note that when doing this, you run the risk of setting the ESP8266's IP address to an address already taken by another device on the same router.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea that I have not implemented yet.

1. Connect to the wifi and let the router assign the IP to it.
2. After getting the IP from the router save that IP to eeprom
3. Now next time you want to connect to the wifi use this code.

```
// Set your Static IP address
IPAddress local_IP(192, 168, 1, 184);
// Set your Gateway IP address
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);

IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 0, 0);
IPAddress primaryDNS(8, 8, 8, 8);   //optional
IPAddress secondaryDNS(8, 8, 4, 4); //optional

if (!WiFi.config(local_IP, gateway, subnet, primaryDNS, secondaryDNS)) {
    Serial.println("STA Failed to configure");
  }
  
  // Connect to Wi-Fi network with SSID and password
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
```

load the saved ip, gateWay and other information saved in the eeprom before passing to wifi.config function.